# Unable to figure out the bug with javascript form validation

Tags: javascript

I'm using the Javascript form validation from here http://webcheatsheet.com/javascript/form_validation.php

When I submit my form, however the validation is not being done. Using firebug, I get the following error (however I have to press escape before the confirmation page is shown)

> fld is undefined validateEmail(fld=undefined) (line 3178)
>   validateFormOnSubmit(theForm=form#form1 /account.php) (line 3137)
>   onsubmit(event=submit )
>
> (3178 out of range 346)

The lines 3178 is basically this piece of code

```
<option value="Tester, Developer, Fisherman and Hunter" >Tester, Developer, Fisherman and Hunter</option>
```

and 3171 is this

```
<option value="Accommodation and Food Services" >Accommodation and Food Services</option>
```

Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: Please show your relevant JavaScript.

Comment: It's not your lines, it's their lines. Anyway, javascript errors will never target an HTML code, so... something here is not right.

Comment: Show the form code and how you are validating the data please

Comment: Here's the link to Pastebin with the full javascript http://pastebin.com/1e1sQBdB

Comment: How are you calling the validation functions? When it says fld is undefined it suggests you're not giving it an element as an argument

Comment: Guys.. Got it narrowed down. What needs to be done if the same validation is put in the same page? That is, form validation as well as newsletter validation?

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail()
  {
  ...
  var vle = validateEmail;
  return !!vle.fld;
  }

function validateFormOnSubmit()
  {
  if (this.validateEmail && this.validateEmail() )
    {
    document.querySelector("#form1").submit();
    }
  else
    {
    ...
    }
  }
```